# Cloud tags sorting and positioning in a fixed-width div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div **with a fixed width** which contains 'tags' like the stackoverflow-tags.

[image: Tag Container - unwanted]

Now, what's disturbing me, is that the `Hallo` Tag is in the last line, but it would fit in the first line. Like this:

[image: Tag Container - wanted]

The order of the elements is irrelevant. So, reordering would be an option.

Question: How can i achieve this? I'm currently using a `<ul><li></li></ul>` construct.

The nicest way would be a CSS-Way, but i guess it's up to JS to solve this problem.
Any ideas would be appreciated :)

**UPDATE** 
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CLj2q/

Comment: If the html is created server-side, it's probably best to order your tags server-side too. Otherwise, where do the data come from?

Comment: CSS can not reshuffle your document automatically, so you're going to be writing Javascript for this. Nasty job though for a lot of reasons. I'll add the jQuery tag to your post since it becomes relevant, judging from the fiddle.

Comment: One possibility is to use server side code to count the number of characters in each string and order them that way (though obviously this would work far better with a fixed width font).

Comment: @steve: just as an update, I add some code to add tags dynamically just for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/CLj2q/13/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it: The jsFiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/CLj2q/19/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('.as-close').click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); });
    DoTagSort();
});

function DoTagSort() {

    var TheItems = [], TheHTML = '';
    var TheLinks = $('.as-selections').find('li').each(function () {
        TheItems.push($(this).text().slice(1));        
    });

    TheItems.sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; });

    var TheTag = '<li class="as-selection-item"><a class="as-close">×</a>';

    while(TheItems.length > 1) {

        TheHTML = TheHTML + TheTag + TheItems[0] + '</li>';
        TheHTML = TheHTML + TheTag + TheItems[TheItems.length - 1] + '</li>';

        TheItems.splice(0, 1);
        TheItems.splice(TheItems.length - 1, 1);
    }

    if (TheItems.length) {
        TheHTML = TheHTML + TheTag + TheItems[0] + '</li>';
    }

    $('.as-selections').html(TheHTML);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not just saying this because i too have answer but this is one crazy solution! Problem is that it rearranges items even if it doesn't really have to and it only works for 2 column list.

Comment: @Bizniztime: which is EXACTLY what the OP asked for: fixed width and he doesn't mind changing the order. You're right that if tags were only 1 or 2 characters wide then it would look odd but that's not what tags are usually about.

Comment: @frencie Yes fixed width. But what is the width? Will it always fit only 2 list elements at max in one row?

Comment: @Bizniztime: I think you're overthinking it: it's about displaying tags. Yes, I get it that it puts 2 tags per row and I think that's very appropriate for this use case. But you're right that if the tags were all 1 or 2 characters long, it would look weird (BTW my solution pairs the longest and the shortest tags); same if a tag were 86 characters wide; same if the box were wider. But this code will work for real-world tags in this particular context. Otherwise, I'm sure there are plug-ins like isotope that will do the work too but these are HUGE compared to the 20 lines or so of code I've got.

Comment: I'm just thinking. And you are uppercasing to much. If one day, for some strange reason, OP tries to change his 'fixed' width to few more pixels your solution breaks down. Also there are tags as 'tea', 'yum', 'kid' which are not that weird.

Comment: @Bizniztime: actually, my solution even works with short tags. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/CLj2q/13/ and test it with 'tea' and 'yum'

Comment: OP seems to like your solution. I would never use it, it is complicated and limited. Why not simply reorder all elements by text size descending?

Comment: @Bizniztime Because, imagine two long words (like `fooooooooo` and `baaaaar`) - you could combine them with short words (like `fo`) so they fit in the same row. if you order by text size, the rows are not filled out and `fooooooooo` and `baaaaar` are in separate rows wasting space.

Comment: @steve Now there are 2 letter tags? Your example just show that for any half-solution like mine or one given there are cases that don't fit.

Comment: @Bizniztime: I added a functionality to add and resort tags. Can you show us an example for which my solution would NOT work and post the link to that jsfiddle?

Comment: @Bizniztime: so the problem you're describing has to do with the fixed-width limitation; "Johnny Bling Bong" is too wide to make anything else fit on the same line. But in reality, this is an edge case and most words and tags aren't going to be "Johnny Bling Bong".

Comment: @frenchie Reality usually doesn't limit itself to our expectations. And no, problem is in second line that has 'Kid' all alone without 'Jim' or any other tag which would fit. Look, it is a really tedious problem to begin with, which i for instance would never even address, and proper solution is far more complicated than beneficial so just be happy that you found good enough solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the container for the tags is a set-width, and the tags themselves aren't (ie: they inherit their width from their contents, rather than us being able to give them a set-width) there's not a huge amount that you can do from the CSS perspective without breaking and re-ordering the flow of the markup.

If the markup is being generated server-side I'm sure you could calculate widths and re-order prior to pushing the markup into the view. If not, you're a bit stuck without using JavaScript.

Given that the order requirement appears to be purely appearance-based (ie: not functional), there's no harm in enhancing the standard float view that you've displayed in your screenshot with JavaScript.  This means that JS-enabled visitors will get an 'enhanced' view (with the elements ordered nicely), whilst non-JS users would still have a fully-functional tag cloud, albeit in a slightly less-organised fashion.

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) would probably do would do exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure Masonry will solve the problem - I think it only works on grid-like layouts. What OP wants is a filler algorithm that determines spare space on all lines and inserts fitting elements from elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you there Niels, but have added Isotope to my answer as an alternative.  Masonry and Isotope both work in the exact way you're describing: an algorithm that grabs elements of the correct width to place in empty spaces in the parent.  I'll ggree that Masonry and Isotope are both most commonly used for grid layouts (and include calculations for height as well as width, which wouldn't be needed in this instance), but their behaviour is exactly what's being asked for in this instance.

Comment: There's nothing to disagree - I was just saying "I'm not sure" based on a scan of the linked page  :)  It's probably like shooting a rubber boat with a cannon though, for flow-based reshuffling there are probably smaller plugins (I don't know them though), or it's not terribly complex to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This is off the shelve solution. And a bit of a cheat with Masonry (notice the columnWidth: 1).

```
   $('.as-selections').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.as-selection-item'
      , columnWidth: 1 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D5ud7/1/

I guess you could find more appropriate library for this or better html form for masonry to crunch.